# Finding the bounding rectangle of text with alignment

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm trying to draw a box around a label which has been aligned using `StringAlignment.Far` for example. I can find the `Size` of text using `g.MeasureString` but I can't find a method to translate the origin point such that I can find a `Rectangle` which bounds the text.

Say I have a `Point origin` at which to draw from, and a `StringFormat format` with what alignment I wish my string to have. I can find the `Size` of the string using `g.MeasureString(text, font)`. How do I translate this `Point/Size` pair into a rectangle which overlaps the `g.DrawString(text, font, brush, origin, format)` call.

Comment: I just found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535831(v=vs.85).aspx but I can't figure out how to use it in C#

Comment: You've got the size of the string.  Exactly where you put it is entirely up to you.

Comment: I know, but given that the functions take a point to draw at and then options as to where to align it against that point, how would I find where to put the size related to the point?

Comment: If the function has a Point argument that says where to draw at then you don't have to guess where to draw at.  You need a Rectangle argument instead.  Now the caller can specify where inside that rectangle you need to draw.  Like left or right and top or bottom.  Right and bottom requires you to know the size of the text.  Not posting a snippet made it unnecessarily difficult for anybody to answer this question btw.

Comment: But I don't know the rectangle in which I want to draw in, only the point which I want to draw from. What I want is some way of translating the point, the size and the *alignment* into a rectangle, which non of the methods supply.

Comment: It should be a little obvious by now that you have a design flaw.  If the caller tells you that it wants text to be aligned to the right but doesn't tell you where the right edge is located then you don't know where to start.  You could arbitrarily take the passed Point.X value as that right edge, then simply subtract the calculated Size.Width to know where to draw.  Unlikely to be very useful.  Compare to [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3cdh3zw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the bounds argument provides the rectangle and the flags argument says how it is aligned inside it.

Comment: but I have no way of knowing what the bounding rectangle is, so you're saying I have to first measure the string then align the Size manually so I can then say what the bounds are?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to convert `c` to managed code. You should use .Net code directly if it's available.

For `MeasureString`, see link [Graphics.MeasureString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 16);
    SizeF sz = g.MeasureString("Text...", font);

    Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0,0, (int)sz.Width, (int)sz.Height);
    Debug.WriteLine(rc.Width.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(rc.Height.ToString());

    //change top/left origin of rectangle
    rc.X = 10;
    rc.Y = 20;
}
```

You just need the width and height of text. You can change left/top corner of [rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

By the way, the C method gives a rectangle with top/left coordinates at zero, so it's the same information as `Size`

---

**Edit**

This will fit text with word-break flag in to a rectangle whose width is 100. The height of the rectangle is not known. `TextRenderer.MeasureText` will tell us the height of the rectangle. Top/left corner can be changed, alignment can be changed.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    Font font = new Font("Arial", 10);

    string text = "I'm trying to draw a box around a label which has been aligned.";
    Size layout = new Size(100, 0);

    Size sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, text, font, layout,
            TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
    Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(new Point(0,0), sz);

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, font, rc,
        SystemColors.ControlText, SystemColors.Control, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I've been using the `g.MeasureString` method which takes `StringAlignment`'s (since I want to align my text when I draw it), but given that those only return sizes how do I find the origin after alignment?

Comment: You are asking how to convert `Point` + `Size` to `Rectangle`, I explained it, and apparently you know that already. Is this multiple lines which you are drawing? Is it for example similar to the formatting of comments in this web page? Which coordinates do you supply, and which coordinates you want to get?

Comment: I'm asking to convert a `Point`, `Size` and `StringAlignment` to a rectangle. or at least translate the `Point` to the upper left corner of the resulting rectangle?

Comment: I added another method to fit text in to a box. This is very commonly used. For example all the text in this web page are formatted the same way. We know the width of the rectangle we want, and we need the TextRenderer to tell the height. But I am not sure if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

My way is use SetMeasurableCharacterRanges to obtain the region of the whole text.
Consider into OnPaint:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
Font font = new Font("Arial", 16);
string text = "Border of this text";

StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

RectangleF area = new RectangleF(0, 0, 246, 84);

sf.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(new CharacterRange[] { new CharacterRange(0, text.Length) });
Region[] r = g.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, area, sf);

Rectangle rf = new Rectangle((int)r[0].GetBounds(g).X, (int)r[0].GetBounds(g).Y, (int)r[0].GetBounds(g).Width, (int)r[0].GetBounds(g).Height);

g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, area, sf);
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), rf);
}
```